# Can StyleCop warnings / errors create Visual Studio todo tasks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

Is there any way for my StyleCop violations being shown in the Resharper To-Do Explorer (or some similar window, I appreciate To-Do tasks are generated from actual content in comments) so I can keep it pinned and track.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper and StyleCop for Resharper plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Resharper's Inspection Results: Resharper->Inspect->Code Issues in Solution.

You would probably need to create your own extension to add To-do comments for each issue so that they would show up in the To-do explorer.

Comment: That is brilliant - thanks very much. I'd missed this before because there was a whole bunch of 'white noise' around the StyleCop issues as there is a whole plethora of issue types included. Thankfully you can open multiple tabs in the window and have different filters in each. Just trying to find the correct balance of filters now - seems some of them are not where I'd expected.

Comment: @Rich: If Piers Myers answers helps you, you should do a upvote. if it is a/the suitable solution you should accept it as solution of you question. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Micha I don't have the required reputation to do an upvote sadly. It's not the perfect solution to what I wanted (eg, having to manually refresh the list), but I have just spotted that I can toggle the accepted solution so for now I shall mark it as accepted and feedback further if I find any better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Rich: Ok, well done (+1 for that). "That is brilliant" -> Sounds like you found perfect solution ;-)

Comment: @Micha I initially typed "That is perfect", then corrected myself. So close, very close :)